# Пропадает ресайз у TableView

Tags: javafx, fxml

После удаления всех элементов в `TableView`, перестают изменятся размеры у `TableColumn` при изменении размера самой таблицы. При том что, когда программа только запущена и элементов еще нет, при ресайзе таблицы все хорошо изменяется.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Удаляю так:

```
@FXML
private void delete () {  
    if (device_table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() != -1)            
    device_data.remove(device_table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());  
    }
```

Comment: установите [setColumnResizePolicy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#setColumnResizePolicy-javafx.util.Callback-) в значение [CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY)

Comment: @АлександрСавостьянов в том то и дело что так и стоит, и по началу все работает , но стоит удалить все элементы , размеры перестают меняются , а если потом добавить элемент , размеры опять подгонятся как надо , что за магия ...